# How to squash with git rebase -i

Tags: git, rebase

I am sort of new to rebasing and definitely haven't squashed commits before.

While checked out to my local branch called 'whatever', I then do a git add and git commit, then rebase.

I guess this is the right way to rebase or at least one way:

```
git rebase -i development
```

development is our mainline branch that we rebase our commits on top of.  When I do that command I get:
[image]

I have to scroll down to see the latest commits that I just tried to rebase on top of the development branch:[image]

I'm no sure what to do at this point. I've obviously committed my changes, and then did a rebase. Is there a command to squash and what do I squash??  I don't want to squash the entire history of the development branch. Is squash something you do *before* you rebase?   I'm lost a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just be able to change the word "pick" to "squash" in order to squash the commit marked "squash" into the preceding commit.

[Git Documentation: Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

An example:

```
$ git log --oneline
acb05b3 Some final commit.
4968dbd Fixing an error in commit df89a81.
df89a81 Something committed too early.
c365eab Another commit...
625889f A commit...
70f29fd The beginning.
```

I want to rebase onto 3 commits before the most recent:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

This gives the following text in a text editor:

```
pick df89a81 Something committed too early.
pick 4968dbd Fixing an error in commit df89a81.
pick acb05b3 Some final commit.

# Rebase c365eab..acb05b3 onto c365eab (3 command(s))
```

Which I change to this:

```
pick df89a81 Something committed too early.
squash 4968dbd Fixing an error in commit df89a81.
pick acb05b3 Some final commit.

# Rebase c365eab..acb05b3 onto c365eab (3 command(s))
```

Upon exiting, I then get another editor containing this:

```
# This is a combination of 2 commits.
# The first commit's message is:

Something committed too early.

# This is the 2nd commit message:

Fixing an error in commit df89a81.

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
```

Which I change to this:

```
# This is a combination of 2 commits.
# The first commit's message is:

This is the squashed commit. It and everything after it get new commit hashes.

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
```

Now if I look at my new history:

```
$ git log --oneline
8792fef Some final commit.
df775c4 This is the squashed commit. It and everything after it get new commit hashes.
c365eab Another commit...
625889f A commit...
70f29fd The beginning.
```

Comment: the weird things is I can't see all the picks in the list, is there  way to scroll up?

Comment: Which commits are missing, what is your current branch, and how does the current branch differ from branch `development`? `git rebase -i development` should attempt to rebase every commit in your current branch that is not already part of branch `development`.

Comment: so I'm checked out to 'mybranch'.  I did a couple git . and git commits.  So my local branch has a few commits.  Then I did a rebase on the development branch (not my branch).  So when I rebase I'm seeing the development branch's history in that pic

Comment: ah ok if I scroll down I can see my latest commits.  not sure why it doesn't just bring me to the bottom in the first place.  I'll add another screenshot

Comment: Ah, it may just have been the ordering that is the source of confusion. Interactive rebase lists commits in the opposite order to `git log`. I.e. Oldest first, newest last.

Comment: ah: "Notice the reverse order. The interactive rebase gives you a script that it’s going to run. It will start at the commit you specify on the command line (HEAD~3) and replay the changes introduced in each of these commits from top to bottom. It lists the oldest at the top, rather than the newest, because that’s the first one it will replay.

You need to edit the script so that it stops at the commit you want to edit" https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: ok I think I'm good, when I wanna squash I assume I just need to specify the commit number only, like I don't have to copy and paste the whole line: de9b1eb Fix PostChecker::Post#urls  I assume I can do like :s de9b1eb or something

Comment: and when you squash, what commit message does it ultimately take in the end when it merges?  I don't want to experiment and f this up, I'm on a new team :)

Comment: If you specify any commits to be squashed, it will open a second text editor after you close the first one, and that text editor will contain the commit messages from all commits being squashed, and will ask you to edit them into a single message.

Comment: As for selecting the commits to squash, you do that by changing the word "pick" in the desired line to "squash", or just "s". I'll add an example.